# Make portion of NSMutableAttributedString clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, nsattributedstring, core-text

I have a multi-line `UILabel` that contains text from a `NSMutableAttributedString`. I want to make a portion of the text clickable.

If I could determine the `CGRect` around the portion of text, I could use the tap location to determine if it falls inside that `CGRect`, but I haven't found a way to do that either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please talk about what you've tried, and why it was not acceptable.

Comment: The only thing I've gotten to work is creating a UIGestureRecognizer for the entire UI label. I've tried to make a CGRect around the clickable text but I haven't found a way to actually make that happen.

Comment: The easiest way is to use `UITextView` with links support. Is that appropriate for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried the following example:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Click me"];
[str addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"http://www.yahoo.com" range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
yourTextView.attributedText = str;
```

Comment: I need to perform an action when the text is clicked... is there a way to use a callback function instead of a URL?

Comment: You can do it by setting a text link delegate on a uitextview - don't think it's possible on a label, but you should be able to make the text view look like your label

Comment: @bdalziel Thanks for the idea, I'll try it tomorrow but I'm so frustrated with trying to figure it out, I'm going to focus on other components for the rest of the night haha

Answer (score 0):

in case you haven't found something yet, you could also try **[ActiveLabel.swift](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift)** which is an `UILabel` drop-in replacement **supporting Hashtags (#), Mentions (@) and URLs (http://)** written in Swift.

Here is a simple example:

```
import ActiveLabel

let label = ActiveLabel()

label.text = "This is a post with a link http://github.com."
label.handleURLTap { (url: NSURL) in
     // do something with the url
}
```

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library.*